# Quicker way to navigate directories in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shortcut, ls

Suppose I'm at a terminal in Linux/UNIX and I run `ls` and see the following displayed:

```
my_file_1.txt my_file_2.txt
```

Now I want to open the first one in gedit, or maybe it's a folder and I want to enter it.

Is running `gedit my_file_1.txt` the fastest way to do this? Suppose the file has a long and awkward name, is there any shortcut along the lines of `gedit ls[0]` - where I'm asking gedit to open the first item in the list returned?

If there's not, I won't lose any sleep over it, but if such a shortcut exists I'd make use of it, especially when dealing with lengthy file and folder names.

Comment: You could always start typing the file name and press tab for autocomplete

Comment: Thanks I feel a little silly for overlooking that! I thought autocomplete was more modern than such terminals - learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
gedit "$(ls | head -1)"
```

But probably using filename completion or cutting and pasting with the mouse will be easier.

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I was looking for. Autocomplete will do the job but I was also curious as to how to achieve it via command.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything that indexes the results of **ls**.

What you could do is the auto-completion feature that is built in. For example if your file name is very long you can just start writing a little bit of the file name and hit 'Tab' until you find the file you need.

Comment: Note it would be trivial to actually "index the results of ls", e.g. by overriding `cd` to both `cd` and index the results of `ls` into some custom environment variable, but there really is no reason to do this since tab-complete is going to be faster and it's hard to keep track of order.

Comment: True, i think the OP realized that.